# create tag block in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tag

Hi How can I define and use in my phtml file custom tag block like this:
''
''
for example this tag create the list of all entries and show the title of them?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Zend Tag for this requirement:

```
$cloud = new Zend_Tag_Cloud(array(

'tags' => array(
        array('title' => 'Code', 'weight' => 50,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/code')),
        array('title' => 'Zend Framework', 'weight' => 1,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/zend-framework')),
        array('title' => 'PHP', 'weight' => 5,
              'params' => array('url' => '/tag/php')),
    )
));

echo $cloud;
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay and how do I use this tag in phtml ?